# Page orientation with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, orientation

When button is clicked; **if all textboxes aren' t empty** on the page it will direct to next page. I made the control it works. But how can i orientate to another page with jquery?

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#registerPage1", function () {
    $(".nextBtn").click(function () {
        if ($(".txt").val().lenght != 0) {
            // i want to write codes for orientation registerPage1 to registerPage2 in here 
        }

        $(".txt").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0 && $(this).next().attr('class') != 'nullInputMsg') {
                ($(this)).after('<div class="nullInputMsg">this field is required!</div>');
            }
            else if ($(this).val().length != 0 && $(this).next().attr('class') == 'nullInputMsg')
                $(this).next().remove();
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have a form named `myform` housing all your textboxes. Lets also assume that the button with the class `nextBtn` is inside this form, and triggers the submit behavior for the form.

Like you did , validating the form on the `click` event of the submit button is fine.However, you'd want to move to the next page only if all the validations pass, so , you should probably leave the redirecting part till the end, by which time you would have determined the results of the validation checks. After that, all that is left to do is

1. Set the action attribute of 'myform` to point to the required page.(It redirectes to this   page)
2. Return false if the validations fail, or true if they pass from the function handling the click event.

So, your code would look something like

```
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#registerPage1", function () {
          $(".nextBtn").click(function () {
              var validationPass = true;

              $(".txt").each(function () {
                  if ($(this).val().length == 0 && $(this).next().attr('class') != 'nullInputMsg') {
                      ($(this)).after('<div class="nullInputMsg">this field is required!</div>');
                      validationPass = false;
                  }
                  else if ($(this).val().length != 0 && $(this).next().attr('class') == 'nullInputMsg')
                      $(this).next().remove();
              });

              return validationPass;
          });

      });
```

Your HTML should probably look like

```
     ....
     ....
      <form id="myform" name="myform" action="RedirectToPage.php" method="get">
        ....
        //form content housing the textboxes and button with class .nextBtn
        ....
      </form>
     ....
     ....
```

Comment: Yes, i did with similar thoughts:
                  $x = "true";
                  $(".requiredText").each(function (i) {
                      if (!$(this).val().length)
                          $x = "false";
                  });
                  if ($x == "true")
                      //commands
                      });
              });
          });

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that by orientation you mean redirection. You don't need jQuery for redirection. Simple javascript will do the job.

```
// works like the user clicks on a link
window.location.href = "http://google.com";

// works like the user receives an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this  $(windows.location).attr('id', 'registerPage2'); but i didn't work. this is working window.location.href = #registerPage2"; i can't write this with jquery?

Comment: There might be a way you could but why would you? This is a clean solution :)